# PDFTron webviewer - how to save the whole redacted pdf to server using ASP.net MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, pdftron

I am currently a developing an application in MVC Core  that is using a PDFTron webviewer. Is there anyway to save the edited pdf edited with pdftron webviewer to the server?

There is a feature of pdftron that saves annotations to the server, but I need to save the whole pdf with the edits to the server.

```
 WebViewer({
          path: '/lib/WebViewer',
          initialDoc: '/StaticResource/Music.pdf', fullAPI: !0, enableRedaction: !0
      }, document.getElementById('viewer')).then(
      function(t) {
        samplesSetup(t);
        var n = t.docViewer;
         
          n.on('documentLoaded', function() {
            document.getElementById('apply-redactions').onclick = function() {
              t.showWarningMessage({
                title: 'Apply redaction?',
                message: 'This action will permanently remove all items selected for redaction. It cannot be undone.',
                  onConfirm: function () {
                      alert( );
                      t.docViewer.getAnnotationManager().applyRedactions()
                   debugger

                      var options = {
                          xfdfString: n.getAnnotationManager().exportAnnotations()
                      };
                      var doc = n.getDocument();
                      const data =   doc.getFileData(options);
                      const arr = new Uint8Array(data);
                      const blob = new Blob([arr], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                      const data = new FormData();
                      data.append('mydoc.pdf', blob, 'mydoc.pdf');
                      // depending on the server, 'FormData' might not be required and can just send the Blob directly

                      const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      req.open("POST", '/DocumentRedaction/SaveFileOnServer', true);
                      req.onload = function (oEvent) {
                          // Uploaded.
                      }; 
                      req.send(data); 
                     
                  return   Promise.resolve();
                },
              });
            };
          }),
          t.setToolbarGroup('toolbarGroup-Edit'),
          t.setToolMode('AnnotationCreateRedaction');
      }
    );
```

When i send the request to the Controller i am not getting the file it is coming null

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveFileOnServer(IFormFile file)
        {
            
            return    Json(new { Result="ok"});
        }
```

Can any one suggest me where i am going wrong
Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JavaScript async function, you need to wait for it completes before doing other things. For example, `AnnotationManager#applyRedactions()` returns a Promise, the same for `AnnotationManager#exportAnnotations()` and `Document#getFileData()`.

For JS async functions, you can take a look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

So here you may want to use `await` to wait for the Promise completes.

Comment: Thank u for  replying i managed to  get it working  , is there any documentation i want to customize  i want the  ui to look like this https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdf-redaction/

Comment: Looks like that webpage is using WebViewer v6.1 which is an old version. You may want to use that version or use legacy UI, see https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/samples/viewing/#viewing-with-legacy-ui.